# Appcelerator App crashes when downloading large (>500mb) zip file

Tags: ios, iphone, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

We are currently developing an iOS-App with Appcelerator which stores media files on the device for later viewing (pdf, mp4, zipped web pages).

We are now facing a problem with files above 500MB which crash the app on iPhone. The app is working on iPad2, but all iPhones tested crash (at random) when downloading these files.

The files are unzipped (all media files come with additional information inside the archive) via ti.compression.

The code used is (broken down to the relevant parts):

```
var zipDownloader = Ti.Network.createHTTPClient({
'onload' : function() {
    var tempname = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10000000) + 1);

    var dir = Titanium.Filesystem.getFile(Titanium.Filesystem.applicationDataDirectory, 'tempDownloads', tempname);
    dir.createDirectory();

    filename = '' + tempname + '.zip';
    var f = Ti.Filesystem.getFile(Ti.Filesystem.applicationDataDirectory, 'tempDownloads', filename);
    f.write(this.responseData);
    var Compression = require('ti.compression');

    var zipFileName = Ti.Filesystem.applicationDataDirectory + 'tempDownloads/' + filename;
    var outputDirectory = Ti.Filesystem.applicationDataDirectory + 'tempDownloads/' + tempname + '/';
    var start = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000);
    var result = Compression.unzip(outputDirectory, zipFileName, true);
    var finished = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000) - start;
    f.deleteFile();
    Compression = null;
    this.callback(outputDirectory);
}
});
zipDownloader.open('GET', url);
zipDownloader.callback = callback; // given in previous code, not relevant
zipDownloader.send();
```

Comment: Do you have a crash log?

Comment: @Shawn Thanks for your question, the answer by miga solved the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the file property of the HTTPClient (https://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.Network.HTTPClient-property-file) instead of writing the file once it is downloaded.

This will work for larger files because it writes the data directly into the file. Otherwise it will try to cache your file first and your app might crash because of memory errors. Tried it with 500+MB files

Comment: If you set the `file` property, will `this.responseText` be empty? And `this.responseData` is just pointing to the saved file which is not loaded into memory?

Comment: not sure, haven't tried that. But you can just ignore it and just use the filename you set before to access the file (it's ready once you are in `onload`

Comment: @miga: Thanks a lot!
This solved the problem.
I totally overlooked this in the documentation.